# Issues In Converting MySQL Result Set To JSON Array To Consume Google GCM API

Tags: php, mysql, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an application in which i will have to integrate GCM functionality.
The device_ids of the recipients are stored in a MySQL database, which are then retrieved and sent to the Google GCM API url, via CURL.
The issue is that i am receiving an error when i do that:

```
 Recipients_Id field is not a JSON Array.
```

The  php code is:

```
      //get the recipients gcm_ids
     if (isset($_POST["deviceid"]) && isset($_POST["message"]) && isset($_POST["recipient_id"])) {
      require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
include_once './GCM.php';
$gcm = new GCM();
 // connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
 $device_id=$_POST['deviceid'];
$recipient_id=$_POST['recipient_id'];
$get_details=mysql_query("select id,name from gcm_users where gcm_regid='$device_id' ");
$row_details=mysql_fetch_array($get_details);
$user_name=$row_details["name"];
 $user_id=$row_details["id"];
$recipients_gcm_ids=mysql_query("SELECT  gcm_regid from gcm_users where id='$recipient_id'");
$rec_gcm1=array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($recipients_gcm_ids))
 {array_push($rec_gcm1,$row);}
$recipients_gcm=array();
$recipients_gcm=json_encode($rec_gcm1);
$message = array("price" => $message1);
$result = $gcm->send_notification($recipients_gcm, $message);


//The class that sends the message to the Google API url
         class GCM {

//put your code here
// constructor
function __construct() {

}

/**
 * Sending Push Notification
 */
public function send_notification($Recipients_Id, $message) {
    // include config
    include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'Recipients_Id' => $Recipients_Id,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "Result Is:".$result;
}
```

I understand that the issue concerns this line of code:

```
 $result = $gcm->send_notification($recipients_gcm, $message);
```

However, i am not aware of any method (yet) that i will use to create a JSON array in PHP except using the "json_encode" function. Perhaps there is a another way to circumvent the :

```
       "Not a JSON Array" error  ?
```

By the way the output of print_r($recipients_gcm) is :

```
    [{"gcm_regid": "ABCDEFGH12y63i4455u65y4i4p4yu4t3i3zzttyuuiioo"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues in the code:

You are sending a json string of reg ids to your send_notification function. Instead, you should have sent an array of reg ids. Try taking out these two lines and use the array `$rec_gcm1` instead.

```
$recipients_gcm=array();
$recipients_gcm=json_encode($rec_gcm1);
```

Call this instead:

```
$result = $gcm->send_notification($rec_gcm1, $message);
```

Next, in send_notification function, change `$fields` to this:

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => $Recipients_Id,
    'data' => $message,
);
```

i.e. change your `Recipients_Id` key to `registration_ids` or else Google GCM server won't be able to parse it.